# How do I get rid of the gap left by an relative positioned div in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, cross-browser

My basic idea is to just a div for highlighting lines.

For IE it works great.  However, in FF I am having a problem.  Is there a standards way people use to do that same function?

I have to switch the highlight div to relative to make the positioning work in FF, but then there is an extra gap before the first line when a line is highlighted.

I am hoping some CSS/JavaScript expert has a workaround.  Also, if there is some normal standards way to do let me know.  I will use that.

Here is a code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function firstChildC(startNode)
        {
            var nextNode = startNode.firstChild;

            while(nextNode.nodeType != 1)  //loop until it is an actual tag, not white space
                nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling;

            return nextNode;
        }

        var bFirefox = false;

        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1)
            bFirefox = true;

        function highlightPosition(event)
        {
            //gets the td that holds the pre tag, which holds the data
            var preTag;
            if(bFirefox)
                preTag = event.target;
            else
                preTag = event.srcElement;

            var containerOfPreTag = preTag.parentNode;
            var lineCountTD = firstChildC(containerOfPreTag.parentNode);
            var numLines = parseInt(lineCountTD.innerHTML);
            var lineHeight = preTag.offsetHeight/numLines;

            //find line to highlight
            var currentLine;
            if(bFirefox)
                currentLine = parseInt(event.layerY / lineHeight);
            else
                currentLine = parseInt(event.offsetY / lineHeight);

            //highlight line
            var highlighterDiv = firstChildC(containerOfPreTag);
            highlightLine(highlighterDiv,0,containerOfPreTag.offsetWidth, (lineHeight*currentLine), lineHeight);

            return 0;
        }

        function highlightLine(highlighterDiv, left, width, top, height)
        {
            highlighterDiv.style.display = "block";
            if(bFirefox)
                highlighterDiv.style.position = "relative";

            highlighterDiv.style.left = left+"px";
            highlighterDiv.style.width = width+"px";
            highlighterDiv.style.top = top+"px";
            highlighterDiv.style.height = height+"px";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body id="page_body">
    <div id="section_content" style="overflow:auto; width:100%;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="line-height:1.1em">
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;">
                    22
                </td>
                <td  style="width: 0px; vertical-align: top;">
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img   style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img   style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img   style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img   style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img   style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td style="font-size:100%;position:relative;">

                    <div style="height: 1.1em; background-color: #f7fa81; position: absolute; z-index:-1">
                    </div>

                    <PRE style="margin: 0px; border: 1px solid #ff0000" onmousemove="highlightPosition(event);">THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 01.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 02.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 03.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 04.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 05.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 06.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 07.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 08.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 09.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 10.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 11.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 12.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 13.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 14.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 15.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 16.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 17.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 18.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 19.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 20.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 21.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 22.</PRE>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't use a framwork like jQuery?

Comment: I am using JSF.  Do you think they are compatible.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is just JavaScript. Well... saying that is much like saying Hibernate is just Java ;) but you get the idea.

Comment: I'd definitely not style those elements using `style` attributes, but using classes instead and a separate stylesheet; doing so you markup is easier to read and maintain. And next time, please don't format your code the way you did (with `pre` and `code` elements and `&lt;` instead of just `<`); simply indent your code by four spaces, e.g. using the code button (the one with `010101`).

Comment: If it works in IE, but not Firefox, you coded it wrong. Never, EVER trust IE to do ANYTHING right. Firefox will show what you wrote. IE makes things up as it goes along. In addition, throwing jQuery at every CSS issue is almost always a waste of resources.

Comment: @Marcel  The code button never seems to work for me.  I always seem to break out of it somehow.

Comment: Strange, what browser do you use? Perhaps you can file your issue at [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the highlight div's position absolute and then look at the following solution.

[How to fix Absolute Positioning In FF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461860/how-to-fix-absolute-positioning-in-ff/4462516#4462516)

Answer (score 1):

Tried to get this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/bemace/Kg2Ag/4/ but it's a mess.

This seems like a much saner approach: (demo'd at http://jsfiddle.net/bemace/DBQFW/)

```
<ul class="code">
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 01.</li>  
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 02.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 03.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 04.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 05.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 06.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 07.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 08.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 09.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 10.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 11.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 12.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 13.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 14.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 15.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 16.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 17.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 18.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 19.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 20.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 21.</li>
<li>THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 22.</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.code {
    border: solid red 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.code li {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: "courier";
    padding-left: 1px;
}
.code li:hover {
    background-color: #F7FA81;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach it is in a lot more network traffic.

Comment: @Grae - More network traffic?  This is a quarter of the size of the original, and if you use an external stylesheet to share it between pages it's even better.

Comment: I would use external JavaScript. Additionally, the user would normally see more than one page at a time. Perhaps they would go to a dozen pages. However, the JavaScript would on need to get downloaded once. If the user used this site each day it might really add up.

Comment: Even with external script, these divs with images take a lot more than an extra <li></li> for each line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to make that work in IE6? Because if not, you can just use `:hover` pseudo-class and get rid of all the script.

Comment: I would need to put each line in some html element.  This would add up to a lot more network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted and replaced your doctype with the same thing and went from 1 validation error to 50. Most of those are 'alt' errors and such but something goofy happened there.

EDIT: The doctype problem may have occured in copy/paste but I still show 56 errors. One of those is your attempt to style the PRE tag, which is invalid.

Comment: I may change that pre tag.  That kind of fits with my solution.