# How to fix Absolute Positioning In FF?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

In IE8 absolute positioning works for being based of the parent.  I can't seem to get it to work in FF.  This is opposite of the problem people normally complain about.

Does anyone have any guess what is wrong?

Grae

Here is a sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function firstChildC(startNode)
        {
            var nextNode = startNode.firstChild;

            while(nextNode.nodeType != 1)  //loop until it is an actual tag, not white space
                nextNode = nextNode.nextSibling;

            return nextNode;
        }

        var bFirefox = false;

        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1)
            bFirefox = true;

        function highlightPosition(event)
        {
            //gets the td that holds the pre tag, which holds the data
            var preTag;
            if(bFirefox)
                preTag = event.target;
            else
                preTag = event.srcElement;

            var containerOfPreTag = preTag.parentNode;
            var lineCountTD = firstChildC(containerOfPreTag.parentNode);
            var numLines = parseInt(lineCountTD.innerHTML);
            var lineHeight = preTag.offsetHeight/numLines;

            //find line to highlight
            var currentLine;
            if(bFirefox)
                currentLine = parseInt(event.layerY / lineHeight);
            else
                currentLine = parseInt(event.offsetY / lineHeight);

            //highlight line
            var highlighterDiv = firstChildC(containerOfPreTag);

            highlightLine(highlighterDiv,0,preTag.offsetWidth, (lineHeight*currentLine), lineHeight);

            return 0;
        }

        function highlightLine(highlighterDiv, left, width, top, height)
        {
            highlighterDiv.style.display = "block";
            highlighterDiv.style.left = left+"px";
            highlighterDiv.style.width = width+"px";
            highlighterDiv.style.top = top+"px";
            highlighterDiv.style.height = height+"px";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body id="page_body">
    <div id="section_content" style="overflow:auto; width:100%;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="line-height:1.1em">
            <tr>
                <td style="display:none;">
                    22
                </td>
                <td  style="width: 0px; vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid red">
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img   style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img   style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img   style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img   style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img   style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img  style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                    <div style='text-align: center; display:block;height: 1.1em; width: 1.1em'>
                        <img style='height: 0.8em; width: 0.8em'/>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td style="font-size:100%;position:relative;">

                    <div style="height: 1.1em; background-color: #f7fa81; position: absolute; z-index:-1">
                    </div>

                    <PRE style="margin: 0px; border: 1px solid #ff0000" onmousemove="highlightPosition(event);">THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 01.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 02.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 03.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 04.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 05.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 06.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 07.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 08.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 09.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 10.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 11.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 12.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 13.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 14.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 15.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 16.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 17.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 18.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 19.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 20.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 21.
THIS IS PAGE 01. LINE 22.</PRE>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some source code and/or a live example might, y'know, help.

Comment: Absolute positioning works based on the **offset parent,** not just the parent. The offset parent of an element `e` is the most immediate ancestor element of `e` which has position other than `static` (the default).

Comment: @Matt What about a relative positioned TD element?  That is what I am trying to use.

Comment: @Kyle Ok, just a minute.

Comment: I would not recommend applying `position: relative` to a table cell. Use a liner div inside of the table cell, set up like this: `<td><div style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;">...</div></td>`

Comment: You should really use an external CSS file and use classes, rather than define styles inline. You will have cleaner and faster code.

Comment: @Matt, I have to check that out.

Comment: @nico I know this is off subject, but can you explain how it is faster?

Comment: @Matt you should put yours as an answer, because I suspect it will be right.

Comment: @Grae: it won't be extremely faster, but the files will be lightier (in terms of byte) so they will take less to load. Also, I'm not 100% sure of how CSS is processed by the browser, but I would expect it to have to recalculate the CSS everytime when it is defined online, and only once if it is a class. Anyway, the biggest improvement would be the readibility of the code.

Comment: @Matt Ball  Your answer worked!  Put it as an answer, and will accept it.

Comment: @Nico, I think I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Grae: [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461860/how-to-fix-absolute-positioning-in-ff/4462516#4462516).

Comment: @Nico: CSS styles are generally computed in a streaming fashion.

Comment: @Nico: I can't find the source right now, but here's the gist (not browser-specific, etc.): HTML content is streamed to the browser from the server. Every time the browser "receives" a new element, it will try to compute its style _right then_, and **not** after the entire page has loaded. See [this article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors) for a more complete explanation.

Comment: @Matt Ball: yes, but that was not my point. I was saying I imagine it to be faster to have only one class (computed only for the first div and applied to the others) rather then having to re-compute the same inline style for each and every div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Lazy copypasta at request of OP:*

Absolute positioning works based on the **offset parent,** not just the parent. The offset parent of an element `e` is the most immediate ancestor element of `e` which has position other than `static` (the default).

---

I would not recommend applying `position: relative` to a table cell. Use a liner `div` inside of the table cell, set up like this:

```
<td>
    <div style="position: relative; height: 100%; width: 100%;">...</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

give the parent element `position: relative`.

Comment: @Grae: In your example give `section_content` position: relative and it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/FWNUR/

Comment: I think your suggestion is basically the same as Matt's

Comment: ah, OK, I didn't notice that... you could add a `margin-left` to the moving div.

Comment: @Grae: yes but i was faster :)

Answer (score 1):

Position relative does not work correctly on td since td is a block-like element and is already getting positioned relatively to the content around it (other tds). Rather nest another div inside td and make that div the relative and than use it to position your absolute content inside.

IE as always get's it wrong here altough display ok.

Comment: Nested the div is correct.  Matt actually said the answer in his comment earlier, so I figure he should get the check.